# negation a logical statement/sentence with quantifier without universe of discourse

Tags: logic, quantifiers

For example, $(\exists x) \,\,\forall y \in Y \,\, P(x,y)$. Here $\exists x$ does not have universe of discourse . In this case, can normal rule for negating the sentence/statement still be used?

Using the rule usually used, negation of the above would be $(\forall x) \exists y \in Y (\neg P(x,y))$, but I am not sure if that's valid.

Comment: Edited my question.

Comment: It is valid. Welcome!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, it is *valid* to negate the statement just as you did.

The negated statement faces the same problem as the original (in that there's lack of a universe of discourse for the quantified $x$), but the negation of the original statement proceeds just as you'd expect it to, and your negation of the original is correct.